# return list 10 times with for. I want 2 numbers to be printed on the screen in each cycle in order

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

There is a place where I hang out. I have a list.

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to return this list 10 times with for. I want 2 numbers to be printed on the screen in each cycle in order. I want the sample output to be:

```
0 - 1
2 - 3
4 - 5
6 - 0
1 - 2
3 - 4
5 - 6
0 - 1
2 - 3
4 - 5
```

What code should I write for such an output? I would be very happy if you answer.
Good work.

Comment: Your output is not 10 times of the list `a`

Comment: What would my list be like this? a=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cycle the list elements, you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). We can call [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) twice on each iteration to get two numbers at a time from the iterator.

```
from itertools import cycle

a = cycle([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])

for _ in range(10):
    print(f"{next(a)} - {next(a)}")
```

**Output:**

```
0 - 1
2 - 3
4 - 5
6 - 0
1 - 2
3 - 4
5 - 6
0 - 1
2 - 3
4 - 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind normally you would have to use `enumerate(a)`, this example only works because your list items are also valid for indexing.

```
for x in range(10): #Repeats 10 times
    for i in a[::2]: #Iterates every other item from list
        if i != 6: #To prevent Index error
            print("{} - {}".format(a[i], a[i + 1])) #Prints output
```

Example output:

```
0 - 1
1 - 2
2 - 3
3 - 4
4 - 5
5 - 6
...
```